# Dynamically adding multiple rows in data table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have been tried to use the DATATABLE for storing the values for the entire application. I haven't use any database for storing values permanently. This are the dummy values I could use through out the application.

**The issue is actually whenever I add a new row value into my DATATABLE it just overrides the previous values in the DATATABLE instead of adding an new row.**

*Is there any chance to add multiple rows to the DATATABLE dynamically and I can use it through out the application session.*

**** MY REGISTER PAGE****

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable myDataTable;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("username");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("firstname");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("lastname");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("password");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("conpassword");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("email");

        myDataTable.Rows.Add("kavi1", "kavi", "rajan", "123456", "123456", "kavi@gmail.com");
        myDataTable.Rows.Add("sri1", "sri", "prem", "123456", "123456", "sri@gmail.com");
        myDataTable.Rows.Add("mani1", "mani", "vanan", "123456", "123456", "mani@gmail.com");
        HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = myDataTable;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {


            if (Session["name"] != null)
            {

                myDataTable = Session["name"] as DataTable;

            }
        }

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myDataTable.Rows.Add(new object []{ TextBox1.Text ,TextBox2.Text,TextBox3.Text , TextBox4.Text,TextBox5.Text ,TextBox6.Text });
        HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = myDataTable;

        if (Session["name"] != null)
        {
            Response.Write("success");

        }

    }
```

**MY LOGIN PAGE**

```
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable dtResult;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtResult = (DataTable)Session["name"];
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < dtResult.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            string un = dtResult.Rows[i].Field<string>("username");
            string fn = dtResult.Rows[i].Field<string>("password");


            if (TextBox1.Text == un && TextBox2.Text == fn)
            {
                //Response.Write("success");
                Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Is it solved or you still have issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue:**

At every `Postback` you are creating a new `datatable` and overriding it to the previous:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDataTable = new DataTable();
        //....
        HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = myDataTable;    //overriding to the previous
```

So when you click on the button to add the new row, it posts back, and recreates a new datatable and then add a new row to that table.

**Solution:**

You just need to modify the `Page_Load` event handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["name"] != null)    //this is you have to do at every postback
    {
        myDataTable = Session["name"] as DataTable;
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //if it is not post back, create a new DataTable and add values to it
        myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("username");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("firstname");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("lastname");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("password");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("conpassword");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("email");

        myDataTable.Rows.Add("kavi1", "kavi", "rajan", "123456", "123456", "kavi@gmail.com");
        myDataTable.Rows.Add("sri1", "sri", "prem", "123456", "123456", "sri@gmail.com");
        myDataTable.Rows.Add("mani1", "mani", "vanan", "123456", "123456", "mani@gmail.com");
        HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = myDataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are correct @shaharyar ...Now it is working fine